# Same R Code, Different Results

Tags: r

I'm redo-ing some of the work I did a few months ago (updating with new ACS data) and my R-code seems to not work anymore.

The problem: when I do the `varimax` rotation

```
princomp(Data, rotation="varimax")
```

it now gives me the exact same results as when I do normal PCA

```
princomp(x = Data, cor = TRUE, scores = TRUE)
```

A few months ago, these produced very different results. Similarly, my correlations and covariance matrices are the same. This means that I'm getting some results, but some of the statistical processes I used to do are no longer working.

Things I've done in the last two months: switch computers, re-download R. These are also different .csv files. Has anyone else had this problem? Is R corrupted?

Comment: "*The `princomp( )` function produces an unrotated principal component analysis.*" - according to http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/factor.html - just like `princomp(~ ., data = USArrests, cor = TRUE, rotation="woop-de-doo")` gives the same results as not specifying a `rotation=` at all. As far as I can tell, there is no `rotation=` argument applicable for `princomp()` at all.

Comment: The `pysch` library excepts a rotation specification with it's function `principal`

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen - it accepts one too.... I'll see myself out.

Comment: It's been one of _those_ days.

Comment: It is not clear which function you are using. Was `princomp` a customized function you didn't `source`?. As pointed out by @thelatemail, there is no rotation possible inside `princomp`. There is a `varimax` function you can run using the output of `princomp`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've figured out the R code. Much appreciated!